# CNAME for subdomains needed?

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname

Hay, I'm having a little trouble.

I have the following domain over at easily.co.uk

```
www.foo.com
```

and i have that site hosted over at 1and1. This site is working fine.

I want to add a subdomain to this site, so i went into Plesk and added the followig subdomain

```
bar.foo.com
```

However, when i point my browser to that subdomain, it fails.

Do i need to setup a CNAME record for this subdomain?

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: "However, when i point my browser to that subdomain, it fails." - What happens when you try to `ping bar.foo.com` or `dig bar.foo.com ANY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell your DNS hosting company to do so. - You can also set up a wildcard record which will direct every possible subdomain to your IP.

Comment: Any idea how to add a wildcard in easily?

Comment: Actually, a wildcard domain isn't going to work in my situation. I also have barbar.foo.com, I'm assuming using *.foo.com every domain will be redirected to foo.com?

Comment: The wildcard record is an `A` record with the name `*` and your desired IP address in your zone file. It will give the same IP for `baz.foo.com` or `qux.foo.com`. It does not have to match with `www.foo.com`.

Comment: the best strategy to setup a subdomain is by giving the subdomain as a CNAME in the zone file and have the local host route that subdomain request to whichever location(IE Virtualhost).

Comment: @dave Using CNAME will require you to change the DNS provider's settings every time you add  anew one. A wildcard will only require you to to create the ViertalHost (which you should do anyway) and it works out of the box. - Yes CNAME can also handle that, but it is a more cumbersome solution especially if you are creating subdomains automatically, you will be required to hook into your DNS provider's API - because you are NOT maintaining your own zone file as it would require two separate machines on two separate subnets which most of us don't have.